# term for a patient’s cells

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Both normal cells and not normal cells can be found in the body of a diseased human being. What adjectives are used in medicine and biology for characterization of such cells?
healthy/normal/intact/... cells ?
diseased/sick/affected/... cells ?

Comment: The question by Diusha has been edited by @Centaurus in a way that deeply changes its meaning. Diusha may want to edit it (back).

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco.     All I did was to correct grammar and spelling.  Anyone can check what I've done.  I've been here long enough and know better than that.

Comment: @Centaurus — You should look (better). You have transformed twice "deceased" into "diseased". Death and disease are not exactly the same thing. :-) You removed "sure". "Sore"?

Comment: I meant “diseased”, not “deceased” :-) Centaurus, thank you for this correction. If I wrote "sure", then I was wrong; I meant “sore”. Thank you, Nicolas Barbulesco.

Answer (score 1):

Healthy cells are also be referred to as normal cells.  The opposite would be "abnormal cells", a generic term. Specific terms abound as do the types of abnormalities you can find: malign, necrotic, hypertrophic, tumoral, dysplastic, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Centaurus. 
Is using of this terms correct in following sentences? 
1. The molecules of the drug can get into both abnormal and healthy patient’s cells. 
2. The molecules of the drug can get into both abnormal and normal patient’s cells.

Comment: @Diusha   I wouldn't use molecules.  That's sort of obvious.  "The drug will get into both healthy and abnormal cells."

Comment: I thought additionally and I seem “abnormal” can be misleading in this context. “Abnormal” can mean the difference from the norm which is not caused by disease. We can say “abnormal” about healthy cell which is too smal, too big or has unusual shape. Correct me please if I wrong.

Comment: @Diusha - I agree that "abnormal" can be misleading. It is better to be precise. So, we may say "affected cells", "diseased cells" or "sick cells" if this is clear in the context. We may precise the defect: "falciform cells" or whatever.

Comment: @Diusha   There is no such thing as a healthy cell being different from its parent cell.  The moment it displays any difference in size, shape or function, it is abnormal.  "Abnormal" is not misleading, it's non-specific. And we, physicians, often use nonspecific terms when talking to the layman.

Comment: @Centaurus In the case when physician or biologist talk to physician or biologist (not to layman), what the word is used? "Abnormal" too? My interest concerns the situation when a disease is told of, but type of disease isn't specified.

Comment: @Diusha   When we don't know what it is, we say "abnormal".  If there is a histologic diagnosis, however, we use the specific term. (e.g. "melanoma cells were found in the lymph node")

Comment: @Centaurus  I'm afraid that we might misunderstand each other. 
In my case, it is necessary that we precisely know diagnosis. We just do not specify and  speak in general. I need the term which would be good in case of any disease, whether it be cancer or sickle-cell anemia. All diseased people have _____ cells.

Comment: @Diusha  Use the generic term: "abnormal cells".  That's what we use in medicine. Other words such as "anomalous", "atypical", "unhealthy" or "bizarre" can only be used in specific contexts.